# pyspark n-gram word counter

Tags: pyspark, counter, n-gram

```
flatMapOp = _loadLines(
        jobName=f'{jobName}.loadLines',
        logDir=logDir,
    )
    rddPD = rdd_prod.flatMap(flatMapOp)
    word_dict = rddPD.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).collect()
```

I have a piece of code as written above in pyspark. I am parallelizing a word counter function. Here _loadLines loads lines from a file and word_dict is a counter of the words present in all files.

I want to modify this to give me a counter of all n-grams, where n can be varied.

For ex, if my file contains the following lines:
She is happy
He is happy and excited

Then the word counter will look like below:
She -1
is - 2
happy - 2
he - 2
and -1
excited -1

Now if I specify n=2, I should get:
She is - 1
is happy - 2
He is - 1
happy and - 1
and excited - 1

Similarly for n=3 and 4.